# Cakephp 1.2 Cookie not Saving Correctly

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-1.2

I am using Cakephp 1.2 (older site) and am trying to implement a cookie.

I have the following Cookie declaration in my app_controller in the beforeFilter() action:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Cookie->name = 'MyCookie';
$this->Cookie->time = '10 Days`s';
//$this->Cookie->domain = '';
$this->Cookie->key = 'securitytoken';
}
```

I have the following in one of my pages (action):

```
 $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('T1');
 echo $cookie;
 echo $this->Cookie->read('T1');
 echo 'a';

//set cookie so we can keep track of this
if(empty($cookie))
{
    echo 'b';
$this->Cookie->write('T1', 'Y');
}

echo 'c';
echo $this->Cookie->read('T1');
echo 'd';
```

When this is run, the output always outputs:

```
abcYd
```

When I run it the second time, it also outputs abcYd, which shouldn't be happening. The second time the T1 cookie variable shouldn't be empty. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies must be sent before any output from your script. try removing the "echo"s statements and see what happens.

Comment: i tried that too and removed the echo's and created the cookie first...i'm thinking its something to do with localhost/virtual directories

Comment: I suggest you try "error_reporting(E_ALL)" at the start of your script to check if PHP is having some troubles which you can't see.

Comment: i used the php cookies, cake's component wasn't working properly for me

Answer (score 0):

Check if your url contains any `#` character and then first remove it.